# Faster iteration than for loop

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have a for loop for a new project, but this form of the code is too slow. I am trying to find the fastest way to resolve it. Maybe as a vector?

I have tried def approach, but it did not execute properly.

```
%%time
for x in df2.index:   
    if x > 0: 
        if (
            (df2.loc[x,'DEF RANK'] == df2.loc[x,'OFF RANK']) 
            & (df2.loc[x,'W']=='nan')
            & (pd.isnull(df2.loc[(x-1),'Event2']) == False)
            & ((df2.loc[(x-1),'Event2'] == 'nan') == False)
        ):
            df2.loc[x,'W'] = df2.loc[(x-1),'W']
        else: # if the above isn't true - pass
            pass
    else: 
        pass
```

Wall time: 6.76 ms

Comment: why use bitwise comparison?

Comment: Your else: pass statements are obsolete unless you were planning to use them later.

Comment: You want to use `np.where` and set `x > 0 ` as a condition for the `if` branch that you currently have. I wouldn't be surprised if this scans the entire DF but, well, we have no example to test with

Comment: is your `df.index` continuous? i.e, does it consist of consecutive integers? What do you want to do with `df2.loc[x, 'W'] = df2.loc[x-1, 'W']`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Python, the bitwise `&` operator does not short circuit. Meaning that all of your comparisons are happening every time, regardless of what the statements before them evaluated to. Try this for a demonstration:

```
bool(print('a')) & bool(print('b')) & bool(print('c'))
```

Outputs:

```
a
b
c
```

Compare that to the `and` logical operator, which does short circuit the chain of comparisons:

```
bool(print('a')) and bool(print('b')) and bool(print('c'))
```

Outputs:

```
a
```

Try subbing out your `&`s with `and`s to limit the number of comparisons being done.

Once you've done that, you can try fiddling with which comparisons should come first. You'll want to order them by either/both which ones are most likely to evaluate to `False` and which ones are most performant.

Answer (score 0):

The first thing you want to learn when dealing with pandas dataframe is to view the data as a whole, and try to deal with it as a whole. So let's dig in your code and see how we can improve it.

```
for x in df2.index:   
    # the next if means you essentially want to look at 
    # df.index > 0 only
    if x > 0: 
        # this if clause chains several 'and' conditions:
        if (
            # this is df2['DEF RANK'].eq(df2['OFF RANK'])
            (df2.loc[x,'DEF RANK'] == df2.loc[x,'OFF RANK']) 

            # this is df2['W'].eq('nan')
            & (df2.loc[x,'W']=='nan')

            # this is df2.loc[df.index - 1, 'Event2'].notnull()
            & (pd.isnull(df2.loc[(x-1),'Event2']) == False)

            # this is df2.loc[df.index - 1, 'Event2'].ne('nan')
            & ((df2.loc[(x-1),'Event2'] == 'nan') == False)
        ):
            # here you copy some position to other position
            df2.loc[x,'W'] = df2.loc[(x-1),'W']

        # if you don't do anything after else, why not delete it?
        else: # if the above isn't true - pass
            pass
    else: 
        pass
```

So with all the comments, how do we write codes that runs faster. Plainly from your code:

```
idx_gt0 = (df.index > 0)
rank_filters = df2['DEF RANK'].eq(df2['OFF RANK'])
w_isnan = df2['W'].eq('nan')

# the next two conditions are more challenging:
# we start with looking at the series  df.loc[df.index-1, 'Event2']
df2['event2_shifted'] = df2.loc[df2.index-1, 'Event2'].values

event2_notnull = df2['event2_shifted'].notnull()
event2_notnan = df2['event2_shifted'].ne('nan')

# now we can merge all filters:
filters = (idx_gt0 & rank_filters 
           & w_isnan & event2_notnull & event2_notnan
          ) 

 # last assign:
 df2.loc[filters, 'W'] = df2.loc[df2.index - 1, 'W']
```

Of course, this is literally translated from your code. But as you said, your code does not work properly. So it would help if you give a sample input data and its expected output.

Answer (score -4):

Unfortunately, there is no good faster way.

Here is one recommendation: change all the `&`s in your code to `and`s.

It may not help that much, though.

You need to use a different programming language, like C, C++, or Java, as compiled code can run faster than interpreted code. If you are willing to get really frustrated, you can try assembly language, but I'm not sure that it is worth it for just a for loop.

Comment: They forgot to add the pandas tag. This code can almost certainly be pushed into C time but they didn't give a testable example. I have added the tag now.

Comment: Could also gain quite a but by using Cython but regardless it's an overly broad question for SO.

Comment: @CME1Crewmember please don't make statements if you are not certain of it. Pythons vectorized solution can be very fast, especially handling data, using pandas & numpy

Comment: @AndyL. There may be slightly faster ways, but I said that there was no **good** faster way. Using a different programming language can make a difference. At the time of answering, he didn't post the full code. I only saw a fragment and so could not suggest a better way.